# Static files on Grails take a while to be available for access via http protocol

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have a Grails 2.3.7 app to serve to store many files and the users can download their files by a URL. But, when they do the upload and try access instantly to the uploaded file by the generated url, get "NOT FOUND" error. If they waiting a second, they can access the file normally.

[image]

Little after I reload the same URL and ...

[image]

I don't if it is the Grails framework processor of resources or the security system of Tomcat 7 for file system. I have removed the Grails plugin of resources (resources:1.2.14) to do this tests. Below is my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"

        mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
        runtime  'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4'
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.53"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.3"
        compile ':cache:1.1.2'

        // Plugin to validate CPF/CNPJ/CEP
        compile ":br-validation:0.3"

        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
        compile ":spring-security-rest:1.3.4", {
            excludes: 'spring-security-core'
        }

        // Excel, Excel 2007 & CSV Importer Using Apache POI
        compile ":joda-time:1.5"
        compile ":excel-import:1.0.0"

        // Plugin to send emails
        compile ":mandrill:0.5"

        // Plugin to generate PDF
        compile ":wkhtmltopdf:0.1.7"

        // Plugin to scale images
        compile ":hd-image-utils:1.1"

        // Plugin to schedule jobs
        compile ":quartz:1.0.2"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.4"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"
        // Resources com webxml
        //runtime ":resources:1.2.14"
        compile ":webxml:1.4.1"
        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        // An alternative to the default resources plugin is the asset-pipeline plugin
        //compile ":asset-pipeline:1.6.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.5.5"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.5.3"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.5.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.1"
    }
}
```

And my Config.grooy:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

// locations to search for config files that get merged into the main config;
// config files can be ConfigSlurper scripts, Java properties files, or classes
// in the classpath in ConfigSlurper format

// grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]

// if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
//    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
// }

grails.project.groupId = appName // change this to alter the default package name and Maven publishing destination

// The ACCEPT header will not be used for content negotiation for user agents containing the following strings (defaults to the 4 major rendering engines)
grails.mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents = ['Gecko', 'WebKit', 'Presto', 'Trident']

// URL Mapping Cache Max Size, defaults to 5000
//grails.urlmapping.cache.maxsize = 1000

// enable only when you need it
//grails.resources.resourceLocatorEnabled = true

// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['**/images/**', '**/upload/**', '**/profile/**', '**/users/**', '**/photos/**', '/css/**', '/js/**', '/plugins/**']
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/upload/*', '/profile/*', '/users/*', '/photos/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
//grails.resources.processing.enabled = false
//grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = []
//grails.resources.rewrite.css = false

// uri-to-url resolution cache timeout in milliseconds
// 0 == caching disabled , -1 == no timeout
grails.resources.uriToUrlCacheTimeout = 30000

// Legacy setting for codec used to encode data with ${}
//grails.views.default.codec = "html"

// The default scope for controllers. May be prototype, session or singleton.
// If unspecified, controllers are prototype scoped.
grails.controllers.defaultScope = 'singleton'

// GSP settings
grails {
    views {
        gsp {
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
            htmlcodec = 'xml' // use xml escaping instead of HTML4 escaping
            codecs {
                expression = 'html' // escapes values inside ${}
                scriptlet = 'html' // escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
                taglib = 'none' // escapes output from taglibs
                staticparts = 'none' // escapes output from static template parts
            }
        }
        // escapes all not-encoded output at final stage of outputting
        // filteringCodecForContentType.'text/html' = 'html'
    }
}

grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
// scaffolding templates configuration
grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'

// Set to false to use the new Grails 1.2 JSONBuilder in the render method
grails.json.legacy.builder = false
// enabled native2ascii conversion of i18n properties files
grails.enable.native2ascii = true
// packages to include in Spring bean scanning
grails.spring.bean.packages = []
// whether to disable processing of multi part requests
grails.web.disable.multipart=false

// request parameters to mask when logging exceptions
grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password']

// configure auto-caching of queries by default (if false you can cache individual queries with 'cache: true')
grails.hibernate.cache.queries = false

// configure passing transaction's read-only attribute to Hibernate session, queries and criterias
// set "singleSession = false" OSIV mode in hibernate configuration after enabling
grails.hibernate.pass.readonly = false
// configure passing read-only to OSIV session by default, requires "singleSession = false" OSIV mode
grails.hibernate.osiv.readonly = false

grails.plugin.wkhtmltox.binary = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf"

grailsApplication.config.hashCode = '2wg2+(APd;&[Ya9'

grails.regex.emailPattern = /[^\s][_A-Za-z0-9-]*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})/

grails.regex.cpfORcnpj = /([0-9]{2}[\.][0-9]{3}[\.][0-9]{3}[\\\/][0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2})|([0-9]{3}[\.][0-9]{3}[\.][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{2})/

grails.regex.cpf = /([0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2})/

grails.regex.cnpj = /([0-9]{2}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\\/]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{2})/

grails.regex.is.file = /^[\w|\W]*(\.)[a-zA-Z0-9]*/

grails.regex.is.url = /^(http|https|ftp)?\:?(\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$/

grails.regex.filesFolder = /^([image|upload]*)\/[\w]*/

grails.statics.ementa = "Ementa - "

environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        sassPath = 'sass'
        courseThemeFolder = "css/"
        uploadFolder = "upload/"
        documentsFolder = "documents/"
        meetingsFolder = "meetings/"
        courseLogoUploadFolder = "images/upload/courses/logos/"
        educationalProjectUploadFolder = "upload/offers/educational_projects/"
        generalSettingsUploadFolder = "upload/general/settings/institution/"
        programOfStudiesUploadFolder = "upload/offers/program_of_studies/"
        meetingTriggersUploadFolder = "upload/meetings/triggers/"
        photosUploadFolder = "upload/users/profile/photo/"
        forumAttachmentFileFolder = "upload/forum/%s/%s/attachments/%s/"
        documentVersionFileFolder = "upload/%s/%s/%s/documents/%s/%s/"
        temporaryFilesFolder = "upload/tmp/"
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/"
        grails.staticUrl = "http://localhost:8080/pemaap/"
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        sassPath = '/usr/local/bin/sass'
        courseThemeFolder = "css/"
        uploadFolder = "upload/"
        documentsFolder = "documents/"
        meetingsFolder = "meetings/"
        courseLogoUploadFolder = "images/upload/courses/logos/"
        educationalProjectUploadFolder = "upload/offers/educational_projects/"
        generalSettingsUploadFolder = "upload/general/settings/institution/"
        programOfStudiesUploadFolder = "upload/offers/program_of_studies/"
        meetingTriggersUploadFolder = "upload/meetings/triggers/"
        photosUploadFolder = "upload/users/profile/photo/"
        forumAttachmentFileFolder = "upload/forum/%s/%s/attachments/%s/"
        documentVersionFileFolder = "upload/%s/%s/%s/documents/%s/%s/"
        temporaryFilesFolder = "upload/tmp/"
    }
}

mandrill {
    apiKey = "0DltTv2M1K6YiSTchRYarg"
}

// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'").format(new Date());
    appenders {
        file name:'file', file:'/var/tmp/logs/pemaap.erros.log'
        environments {
            development {
                rollingFile name: "file", maxFileSize: 1024,
                            file: ("/tmp/dev/logs/" + fileName)
            }
            production {
                rollingFile name: "file", maxFileSize: 1024,
                            file: ("/tmp/prod/logs/" + fileName)
            }
        }
    }
    root {
        error 'stdout', 'file'
    }
}

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.UserAccessProfile'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'br.com.tokenlab.pemaap.AccessProfile'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll'],
    '/dbconsole/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/user/login':                    ['permitAll'],
    '/user/logout':                   ['permitAll'],
    '/**/upload/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/users/**':                   ['permitAll'],
    '/**/photos/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/files/**':                   ['permitAll'],
    '/**/tmp/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/users/**':                   ['permitAll'],
    '**/profile/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '**/photo/**':                    ['permitAll'],
    '**/upload/users/profile/photo/**':['permitAll']
]

cors.headers = ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, authorization, accept, content-type, x-requested-with, X-Auth-Token',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS']

accessProfile.type = [
    ["id": "1", "name": "Cliente"],
    ["id": "2", "name": "Prestador de Serviço"]
]

alternative.text = [
    ["text": "Satisfatório / Insatisfatório / Sem emissão de conceito", "alternatives": ["Satisfatório", "Insatisfatório", "Sem emissão de conceito"]],
    ["text": "Satisfatório / Insatisfatório", "alternatives": ["Satisfatório", "Insatisfatório"]]
]

email.sender.address = "iep@tokenlab.com.br"
//email.sender.address = "ufscar@tokenlab.com.br"

format.assessmentCategory = [
    ["id": "1", "name": "Formativa"],
    ["id": "2", "name": "Somativa"]
]

format.category = [
    ["id": "1", "name": "Avaliação de Atividade"],
    ["id": "2", "name": "Avaliação de Curso"],
    ["id": "3", "name": "Avaliação de Desempenho de Pessoas"]
]

format.defaultConcepts = [
    [
        "id": "0",
        "concepts": [
            "Satisfatório",
            "Insatisfatório",
            "Sem emissão de conceito"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id": "1",
        "concepts": [
            "Satisfatório",
            "Insatisfatório"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id": "2",
        "concepts": [
            "Satisfatório",
            "Precisa melhorar",
            "Sem emissão de conceito"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id": "3",
        "concepts": [
            "Satisfatório",
            "Precisa melhorar"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id": "4",
        "concepts": [
            "Satisfatório",
            "Insatisfatório",
            "Não utilizei",
            "Sem emissão de conceito"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id": "5",
        "concepts": [
            "Satisfatório",
            "Insatisfatório",
            "Não compareci",
            "Sem emissão de conceito"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id": "6",
        "concepts": [
            "Satisfatório",
            "Insatisfatório",
            "Não se aplica",
            "Sem emissão de conceito"
        ]
    ]
]

individualPerson.gender = ["Masculino", "Feminino"]

meeting.movements = ["Avaliação", "Nenhum"]

offer.schemes = ["Anual", "Ciclo", "Semestral"]

offer.attendanceSchemes = ["Anual", "Semestral", "Todo o Curso"]

question.types = [
    ["id": "1", "name": "Dissertativa"],
    ["id": "2", "name": "Objetiva - Múltipla Escolha"],
    ["id": "3", "name": "Objetiva - Resposta Única"]
]
```

PS: The files was stored in the same machine as web app, in same domain but in other port. The uploaded files was moved into system folders, inside the grails web-app folder by ascyncron process upload. The frontend app send a request to grails backend app and wait for some response. In this time, grails try upload the file and move it to final folder.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to really get any reliable help.  Guessing would be required in order to provide an answer.  How are the files being uploaded? Are they being stored on the file system?  Are they being stored on the same machine as the web app?  Is the process that receives the upload synchronous? Etc...

Comment: Really I forgot this informations, sorry. So, the files was stored in the same machine as web app, in same domain but in other port. The uploaded files was moved into system folders, inside the grails web-app folder by ascyncron process upload. The frontend app send a request to grails backend app and wait for some response. In this time, grails try upload the file and move it to final folder.

Comment: You just answered your own question. There is a process in which files get copied to the final location. This is your delay. Also, storing uploaded files in the web-app folder is a bad idea. When your app is re-deployed, those files will be gone since they are not part of the WAR.

Comment: So @Gregg, what you suggest to do? Store the files in File System of SO?

Comment: Store them anywhere except web-app. Generally, you'd have a file server in your topology. But if you're small scale, just save them to the same file as your app. Just not within your app structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you need take file uploads, a great option is in an Amazon S3 bucket.  There are plugins to help make getting them there easy, and you'll never need to worry about losing the files, and the cost is extremely minimal.

https://grails.org/plugin/aws-sdk